# error C2664: 'errno_t wcstombs_s(size_t *,char *,size_t,const wchar_t *,size_t)' : cannot convert parameter 4

Tags: c++, winapi

> error C2664: 'errno_t wcstombs_s(size_t *,char *,size_t,const wchar_t *,size_t)' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'CHAR [260]' to 'const wchar_t *' 1>
>   Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

What does this error mean?

As my function is:

```
BOOL DependentDLLDisplay()
{
    char arr[200];

    if(!Module32First(hProcessSnap,&me32))
    {
        cout<<" ERROR : Failed to Get DLL Information"<<endl;
        CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
        return FALSE;
    }

    cout<<endl<<"DEPENDENT DLL OF THIS PROCESS :"<<endl;
    do
    {
        wcstombs_s(NULL,arr,200,me32.szModule,200);
        cout<<arr<<endl;
    }while(Module32Next(hProcessSnap,&me32));

    CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have a non-Unicode build so `me32.szModule` is already ANSI. No need to convert it.

Comment: Check your project settings to see of you are configured for UNICODE or MBCS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object `me32` is of the type `MODULEENTRY32` as defined here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684225.aspx

The `szModule` field that you pass as the 4th parameter to 'wcstombs_s` is defined as:

```
TCHAR   szModule[MAX_MODULE_NAME32 + 1];
```

In the Windows API, `TCHAR` is defined as `char` in MBCS encoding, and `wchar` in UNICODE encoding.

The error you are seeing is indicating that you are including the MBCS version of the Windows library, thus `MODULEENTRY32` is actually `MODULEENTRY32A` and `me32.szModule` is a `char[]`, but are then trying to treat `me32.szModule` as if it were a wide `wchar_t[]`  string when it is in fact an Ansi `char[]` string.

You can either switch to the UNICODE libraries by changing your project settings, or using a normal `char` string copy to obtain the value of that field.

Or, as Remy stated:

> Or, you can explicitly use `Module32FirstW()`/`Module32NextW()`,
>   `MODULEENTRY32W`, `std::wcout`, etc, or explicitly use
>   `Module32FirstA()`/`Module32NextA()`, `MODULEENTRY32A`, etc. Either way, you
>   do not have to change the project settings. Don't use `TCHAR`-based APIs
>   anymore. In this case, since the code wants to end up with a `char[]`
>   string, it makes sense to use `Module32FirstA()`/`Module32NextA()` and
>   just remove `wcstombs_s()` altogether.

One last note: You should probably expand your local variable to be the same size of `szModule` rather than potentially truncate the contents.

Comment: Thanks so much... Got it now... 
I had confusion so i have used that instead directly using char string

Comment: Or, you can explicitly use `Module32FirstW()`/`Module32NextW()`, `MODULEENTRY32W`, `std::wcout`, etc, or explicitly use `Module32FirstA()`/`Module32NextA()`, `MODULEENTRY32A`, etc. Either way, you do not have to change the project settings.  Don't use `TCHAR`-based APIs anymore, unless you need to support Win9x/ME. In this case, since the code wants to end up with a `char[]` string, it makes sense to use `Module32FirstA()`/`Module32NextA()` and just remove `wcstombs_s()` altogether.